# Spring Security and SiteMinder integration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, siteminder

I'm trying to integrate SiteMinder with Spring Security. I have a logout button on home page which is supposed to make http get request to backend. I'm trying to invalidate session and redirect back to home page. It's supposed to automatically navigate to log in page which is set up in apache. unfortunate it's not invalidating session or delete cookies. 
This is my

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .addFilterBefore(ssoHeaderFilter(), RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authenticationProvider(ssoAuthProvider())
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logoutPage")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "GPSESSION")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers( "/**")
            .hasRole("ADMIN");

}
```

AuthenticationController

```
@RequestMapping(value="/logoutPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        request.logout();
}
```

SSOAuthenticationProvider

```
public class SSOAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSSOAuthenticationProvider.class);
    public static final Map<UserAuthority, UserAuthority> roleMap = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        roleMap.put(UserAuthority.ADMIN, UserAuthority.ADMIN);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        UserDetailsBean user = (UserDetailsBean) authentication.getPrincipal();
        LOGGER.info("Inside WebSSOAuthenticationProvider authenticate method");
        if(isValidRoles(user.getRoles())){
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, authentication.getCredentials(),
                    getAuthoritiesByRoles( user.getRoles()) );

        }
        throw new BadCredentialsException(user.getFirstName() + " has not valid roles");
    }

    private boolean isValidRoles(Set<UserAuthority> roles) {
        return roles != null && roles.stream().filter(roleMap::containsKey).findAny().isPresent();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return true;
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthoritiesByRoles(Set<UserAuthority> roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = roles.stream().map(v ->  v.name()).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return authorities;
    }
```

SSOAuthenticationFilter

```
public class SSOAuthenticationFilter extends RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SSOAuthenticationFilter.class);
    @Value("${project.ui.test.mode:false}")
    private boolean guiTestMode;
    private String FIRST_NAME = "sso-givenname";
    private String LAST_NAME = "sso_surname";

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
        LOGGER.debug("Working in the test mode for logging");
        Enumeration<String> names = request.getHeaderNames();
        LOGGER.info("Going to print all http headers");
        while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
            String name = names.nextElement();
            String value = request.getHeader(name);
            LOGGER.info("name: " + name + ", value: " + value);
        }
        UserDetailsBean user = new UserDetailsBean();
        if(isTestMode()){
            user.setFirstName("Mock");
            user.setLastName("User");
            user.setRoles(new HashSet<UserAuthority>(Arrays.asList(UserAuthority.ROLE_P_AND_S)));
            request.getSession().setAttribute("user" , user);
            return user;
        }
        user.setFirstName(request.getHeader(FIRST_NAME));
        user.setLastName(request.getHeader(LAST_NAME));
        user.setRoles(new HashSet<UserAuthority>(Arrays.asList(UserAuthority.ROLE_P_AND_S)));
        request.getSession().setAttribute("user" , user);
        return user;
    }
    private boolean isTestMode() {
        return guiTestMode;
    }
}
```